# How to specify two math.floor values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I specify a 20% value and a 100% value using Javascript?

This is my current code: `${Math.floor((scooter.attributes.meter_range / 24140) * 100)}%`

I want to change it so that **965 = 20%** and **24140 = 100%**

This is what I'm currently getting when I have it set to 965 = 20%:
[image]

The battery should be at minimum 20% and at maximum 100%

How can I do this?

Sorry for not explaining it very clearly.

Comment: 20% and 100% of what? If you need two different percentages, just make two calculations. `let p1 = v1/24140 * 100; let p2 = v2/24140*29;`

Comment: I'm working on an answer right now, it might take a little bit. Just making sure, you want a linear value where `965` returns `20%` and `24140` returns `100%`, so `8000` returns ~`44.321%` (and then floored)

Comment: Thank you @Samathingamajig. That exactly what I need. I get the data through an API, and it only outputs meter range and not actual battery percentage (this is an electric scooter) 965 is the lowest I've ever seen so that equals 20% and 24140 equals 100%. But I'm getting weird numbers when using the code above. I've updated my post to include an image of what's currently happening.

Comment: Does this API have SOC documentation? Does it tell you the range is X through 24140?

Comment: https://github.com/ubahnverleih/WoBike/blob/master/Lime.md After vehicles have been freshly deployed, I've sent out a GET request to the API and 24140 is the range that shows. I haven't seen anything higher than that so I guess that's the top amount. 965 I know for a fact is 20% so I know that one.

Comment: It's not a correct function. How do you calculate them? 965 = 20%, so 965 * 5 = 4825 ???

Comment: @Mr. (algebra, with slope and y-intercept)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want a linear conversion, since you only specified two points, we can use some algebra to solve your problem.

First, find the slope.

[image: Slope = \frac{rise}{run}]

or in other words,

[image: Slope = \frac{verticalChange}{horizontalChange}]

The variable `m` is used in mathematics to describe the slope. With two points, we can use this formula to find the slope:

[image: m = \frac{y2-y1}{x2-x1}]

And for this case, we will use these values for x1, x2, y1, and y2:

```
x1 = 965
x2 = 24140

y1 = 20 //(Using whole numbers since you're already adding the % sign)
y2 = 100
```

So substituting, we get:

[image: m = \frac{100-20}{24140-965}]

So `m` is about `0.00344976282881` (you would calculate this on the fly in code, not hardcode it)

So we have the slope now. What next? We need to find the y-intercept and the entire function.

Using the point-slope form, we can find these two last things.

The point-slope form looks like this:

[image: y - y1 = m(x - x1)]

And some rearranging:

[image: y = m(x - x1) + y1]

And replacing:

[image: y = 0.00345(x - 965) + 20]

(Note: the slope is truncated just for viewing)

So now we have a function.

To generalize it, we need to recombine all the formulas.

[image: y = (\frac{y2 - y1}{x2 - x1})(x - x1) + y1]

Converting this into a JavaScript function: (I'm using ES6 style function)

```js
const linearRescale = (x, x1, y1, x2, y2) => ((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1))*(x - x1) + y1;
```

Here's a snippet to show this working:

```js
const linearRescale = (x, x1, y1, x2, y2) => ((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1))*(x - x1) + y1;

console.log(linearRescale(965, 965, 20, 24140, 100)); // 20
console.log(linearRescale(24140, 965, 20, 24140, 100)); // 100

// Without flooring
console.log(linearRescale(8000, 965, 20, 24140, 100)); 
console.log(linearRescale(16000, 965, 20, 24140, 100));
console.log(linearRescale(20000, 965, 20, 24140, 100));

// With flooring (~~ truncates the number)
// Use Math.floor though, this is just for cleanliness here
console.log(~~linearRescale(8000, 965, 20, 24140, 100)); 
console.log(~~linearRescale(16000, 965, 20, 24140, 100));
console.log(~~linearRescale(20000, 965, 20, 24140, 100));
```

Another thing you can do, if using something like this again, but you're doing it multiple times is to use currying. In basic terms, currying returns a function.

```js
const linearRescale = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => x => ((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1))*(x - x1) + y1;
```

```js
const linearRescale = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => x => ((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1))*(x - x1) + y1;
const myLinear = linearRescale(965, 20, 24140, 100);

console.log(myLinear(965)); // 20
console.log(myLinear(24140)); // 100

// Without flooring
console.log(myLinear(8000)); 
console.log(myLinear(16000));
console.log(myLinear(20000));

// With flooring (~~ truncates the number)
// Use Math.floor though, this is just for cleanliness here
console.log(~~myLinear(8000)); 
console.log(~~myLinear(16000));
console.log(~~myLinear(20000));
```

Now that we have these results, just concatenate with `"%"` and you have your battery percentage.

```js
const linearRescale = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => x => ((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1))*(x - x1) + y1;
const myLinear = linearRescale(965, 20, 24140, 100);

console.log(`${myLinear(965)}%`); // 20
console.log(`${myLinear(24140)}%`); // 100

// Without flooring
console.log(`${myLinear(8000)}%`); 
console.log(`${myLinear(16000)}%`);
console.log(`${myLinear(20000)}%`);

// With flooring (~~ truncates the number)
// Use Math.floor though, this is just for cleanliness here
console.log(`${~~myLinear(8000)}%`); 
console.log(`${~~myLinear(16000)}%`);
console.log(`${~~myLinear(20000)}%`);
```

Here's a Desmos link of your equation: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xmrbpugvdx

Comment: Thank you. The "`%`" wasn't for the math, it was just to go on the end of the Battery Level in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
const calc = (x) => {
    return ((16*x)/4635) + (15452/927)
}
```

Results:

```
calc(965) => 20
calc(8000) => 44.284...
calc(24140) => 100
```

Based on the [graph](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/algebra-1/slope-intercept-form-calculator-with-two-points/?px=965&py=20&qx=24140&qy=100&steps=on) `y = mx + c` through the points (965,20) and (24140,100) where:

- m = 16/4635
- c = 15452/927

Comment: @Samathingamajig it was written and submitted independently of your answer. That sometimes happens when people work on answers in parallel.